# Can't get airflow AWS connection to work "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.amazon"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow

I have been trying to run a simple Airflow DAG to show what's in an s3 bucket but I keep getting this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.amazon'`

I've tried several pip installs recommended in similar questions but still have no luck. Here's the python script and below is a screenshot of my Airflow webserver showing the error message. Note I'm using Airflow version 2.5.0

```
import datetime
import logging

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.hooks.S3_hook import S3Hook

def list_keys():
    hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id='aws_credentials_old')
    bucket = Variable.get('s3_bucket')
    prefix = Variable.get('s3_prefix')
    logging.info(f"Listing Keys from {bucket}/{prefix}")
    keys = hook.list_keys(bucket, prefix=prefix)
    for key in keys:
        logging.info(f"- s3://{bucket}/{key}")


dag = DAG(
        'lesson1.exercise4',
        start_date=datetime.datetime.now())

list_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="list_keys",
    python_callable=list_keys,
    dag=dag
)
```

[image]

Comment: can you show us the commands that you ran to install the provider?

Comment: Hey Kulasangar - I ran the same pip install strider shared in his answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the backport-providers-amazon package because it's only available in the Airflow main branch.

```
pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-amazon
```

Here you can find more info. https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-amazon/

Comment: Thanks strider - I've tried this as well and still getting the same error message I shared above :(

Answer (score 0):

You are importing from the wrong place. It should be

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook
```